# Sort by rate from homes with multiple rates

Tags: mysql, sorting, sql-order-by

I am developing a holiday rentals site and each home has multiple rates. So I have a table homes and a table rates. When I fetch the using this sql

```
SELECT * 
  FROM homes 
  INNER JOIN rates ON rates.home_id = homes.id 
  GROUP BY homes.id 
  ORDER BY rates.price ASC
```

the results are not correct. I get mixed prices and from minimum to maximum. I think the problem is that there are mupltiple rates for each home. So how can I find the minimum rate and sort by it?

Comment: ASC is from minimum to maximum. What exactly do you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM homes INNER JOIN rates ON rates.home_id = homes.id GROUP BY homes.id ORDER BY min(rates.price) ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT homes.*,r.min_price FROM homes INNER JOIN
(SELECT home_id,MIN(price) min_price FROM rates GROUP BY home_id) r
ON r.home_id = homes.id
ORDER BY r.min_price;
```